# select multiple node to remove

Tags: c#, xml

It's been hours I'm figuring this but no luck. I'd like to ask how to remove multiple nodes.

When I did Single node I don't have any problem but when I added condition "OR" or else if it always remove the whole nodes.

Hope somebody could help.

Here is what i have done so far:

XML

```
<ApplDetails>

<NodeLog>
<PName>
test123
</PName>
</NodeLog>

<NodeLog>
<PName>
test125
</PName>
</NodeLog>

<NodeLog>
<PName>
test126
</PName>
</NodeLog>

</ApplDetails>
```

c# Codes

```
XmlDocument xdoc1 = new XmlDocument();
xdoc1.Load("D:\\nodes.xml");
foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc1.SelectNodes("ApplDetails/NodeLog"))
{

    if (node.SelectSingleNode("PName").InnerText != "test123"  || node.SelectSingleNode("PName").InnerText != "test125"   )
    {
        node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
    }

}

xdoc1.Save("D:\\nodes.xml");
```

Comment: FYI, if you're just learning, then you should not use `XmlDocument`. Read up on "LINQ to XML".

Comment: thanks Sir. Sir may I know so what I did is not possible to achieve using XmlDocument? ok sir I'll read about Read up on "LINQ to XML".

Comment: `XmlDocument` is the old way. Don't bother learning it. Learn LINQ to XML instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value cannot be equal to `test123` and at the same time to `test125` so the condition is always `true` (at most one clause can be `false` - try for `test123` and you will get `'test123' != 'test123' || 'test123' != 'test125'` - the first clause is `false` but the second is `true` so the expression evaluates to `true`). If you want to remove all the elements whose value is not 'test123' and not 'test125' you need `&&` and not `||`.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ to XML:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\nodes.xml");
xDoc.Root.Elements("NodeLog")
    .Where(w => (string)w.Element("PName") == "test123" || (string)w.Element("PName") == "test125")
    .Remove();
xDoc.Save(@"D:\nodes.xml");
```

Comment: Hi Sir may I know if this will work on framework 2.0 ? I need to run it framework v 2.0

Comment: Good day, squire. You did not mention framework 2.0 in your original question.